# Could not figure out OD cost matrix message

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I have street nodes as the origin points (I have 19,133 for the whole area) and grocery stores(I have 9 of them in all) as the destination points.  After clicking on the solve button for the OD cost matrix analysis, I get a message display as shown in the sample that I attached.  (Not all origins get connected by straight lines to the destination, I get only a few of these origins that connect)

Anyone could help me out with this issue?

[image]

@fatih_dur I tried using the topology toolset to correct errors in the road network.  After running the error inspector, I found out that there are 116 errors.  I was trying to correct using the "Fix Error Tool" but I could not proceed.  Could you help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That most probably means your network needs a revision. Firstly you need to make sure snap distance is large enough to capture all your origins. This is basically to create imaginary lines to connect your origin/destination POINTS to the network LINES.

If this does not help, then you need to check if your network's connectivity is topologically correct (lines meet at the nodes -no overshoots/undershoots, which applies to both 2D and 3D features. In 3D you may need to check latitude/Z) and attributes such as driving directions are introduced correctly, if any. The quickest trick for linework fixing is to use "Planarize Lines" tool in the editing toolbar. This will make sure there will be a node at each lateral intersection (be aware that this is 2D connectivity). You  can also use Topology toolset to find offending features, e.g., dangles, crossovers, etc. Attribute-wise, you can test your network without defining driving directions (or one-lane attribution).